# How do i put ubuntu onto a laptop through USB

Tags: system-installation, usb

Last year my windows 8 Samsung 64x laptop died on me, and so did the partition i suppose. So I built a tower that barely scrapes by. My uncle just told me that he uses Ubuntu for one of his computers and it can be put onto the laptop through a USB So I installed the Ubuntu USB loader and the latest Ubuntu system. It's a .ISO file as i imagine it was supposed to be. When it was finished transferring i plugged it into the laptop and nothing loaded. I looked all over the bios and found nothing that suggested USB. Just for further information, It's a brand new PNY 16GB Flashdrive bought today and when i loaded Ubuntu onto the USB i selected the format option as well.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply put an `ISO` file onto a flashdrive and boot from it. You need to make it correctly. There are instructions on how to make a bootable Ubuntu installer on a USB stick at:
[How to create a bootable USB 
stick on Windows - ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
[How to create a bootable USB 
stick on Mac OS X - ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)

And if for some reason you need it: [How to create a bootable USB 
stick on Ubuntu - ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu)